# Retrieving precision and scale from a literal value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to check the precision and scale for a given value during a SELECT in MySQL ?

Something like:

```
SELECT
  IF(PRECISION(:value)<=d.precision AND SCALE(:value)<=d.scale, 'OK', 'ERROR')
FROM definition d;
```

With `:value` being any decimal literal value (eg. `123` or `123.45`).

ps.: I cannot afford to have user-defined functions, and would like to avoid introducing blocks and variables.

Comment: How about Length()?

Comment: length returns the length of the string representation, not the value (eg. length(123.450) => 7). I still have problems with the dot (if any) and trailing zeroes (if any).

Comment: It was intended as a clue.

Answer (score 1):

I can advice next solution:

```
SELECT 
    @VAL:=ABS(@VAL) `ABS`, -- get ABS value
    @L:=LENGTH(@VAL) `L`, -- get LENGTH
    @DP:=LOCATE('.', @VAL) `DP`, -- LOCATE point sign
    IF(@DP>0, (@L - 1), @L) `PRECISION`, -- calculate PRECISION
    IF(@DP>0, (@L- @DP), 0) `SCALE`; -- calculate SCALE
```

Result on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=824461e79f73e2703ca60a825e1c67d7&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

```
+================+====+====+===========+=======+
| ABS            | L  | DP | PRECISION | SCALE |
+================+====+====+===========+=======+
| 4122.100000000 | 14 | 5  | 13        | 9     |
+----------------+----+----+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: I guess the only way to go is indeed through string manipulation, which somehow defeats the purpose of having a type system. Anyway you inverted the notions of precision and scale, and leading (and trailing, in case of a dot) zeroes are probably not part of the precision and scale, and should be trimmed.

Comment: Sure, I fixed my mistake with  PRECISION & SCALE, but I'm tot agree to trim trailing zeroes. All zeros after the decimal point indicate more precision.